# Change variable number of variables in a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to do something like this :

```
bool val = false;
bool val1 = false;
...

void function(&val,&val1,...)
{
   val = false;
   val1 = true;
   val15 = false
   ...
}
```

I know how to pass a variable number of arguments to a function (va_arg) however i don't know how to do the same with references. Thank you for your help and i'm sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Are all arguments of the same type?

Comment: if all agruments are of the same type you can pass an `std::vector` by reference instead

Comment: all arguments are the same type. thank you for that but is there any other way? without vectors?

Comment: is there any specific reason why you don't like the vector idea?

Comment: just a personal preference, if there isn't any other way i will stick to vectors.

Comment: Maybe: `std::tie(val, val1, val15, ...) = std::make_tuple(false, true, false, ...);`?

Comment: Having a pile of variables is usually an anti-pattern, especially if they're somehow related. Use `std::vector` ideally for this.

Comment: If you want to pass a set of values, you need to pass something - or a reference to something, or a pointer to something - that contains them.   Any data structure will do, whether it's a standard container (`vector`, etc), other standard type (e.g `tuple`), or something you roll yourself.

Comment: thank you for all your help guys. you can mark this as solved ( if i can do that i will do it as soon as i figure out how )

Comment: Just delete the question since it no longer needs to be answered.